# Gaussian Processes for Regression (GPR) and Logistic Regression (LR)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics

I want to implement a model for risk prediction (generate a percentage). I know LR would be adequate to this work but I would like to try GPR.

My question is: is GPR a suitable choice in this case? I know GPR is to generate probability distribution over function and it can give robust estimation for missing data but is it possible to make probabilistic prediction? (or Gaussian Processes for Classification can do this?)

Thank you for your help.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

GPR is for Regression problem. LR is for **"Classification"**.

You should use Gaussian Process followed with a nonlinearity (like a softmax) for classification which needs some approximations for learning and prediction. It is included in the following link. You can run the demo to see how it works: 
http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression is a regression method for binary response variables (almost what @Daniel says, but not quite). If your risk can be interpreted as a probability of default/collapse/whatever, then Logistic Regression might be appropriate if you can arrange your data to have either "defaulted" or "not defaulted" instead of the risk percentage as the dependent variable.

If not, you're somewhat stuck with regressing against the percentage. You could use Gaussian processes, or indeed any other regressor. The reason I say 'stuck' is that there are some problems with regressing against numbers bound to the interval [0, 1] using standard methods, as a standard linear regressor (or GP, or SVR, or whatever) is usually defined over the entire real line. To get around this, you can specifically use Beta Regression (y ~  Beta) which confines the dependent variable to the appropriate range, or regress against a transformed percentage (for example, the logit or probit transformed proportion will be on the entire real line).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Just a quick question: I've read some tutorial materials on GP for classification (GPC) and I'm a little confused that if GPC can deal with multi-dimensional binary data (like SVMs)?